# How to make mitmproxy to intercept all traffic from all ports using a reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, man-in-the-middle, mitmproxy

I have 3 machines:
1. An application which uses different databases and other services.
2. Proxy (mitmproxy) (192.168.56.51)
3. Server with all databases and services which are required for the application. (192.168.56.50)

All 3 machines are in the same local network running Centos 7.

Right now machine 1 is using databases and services on machine 3.

My task to use the machine 2 as it would be a machine 3 and show all the traffic. I.e. I need to be able to listen to all ports on machine 2 and redirect traffic on equivalent ports on machine 3.

I made port redirects to mitmproxy port (8080) on machine 2 in iptables:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23:8079 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8081:65000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Also, added forwarding to machine 2:
**/etc/sysctl.d/mitmproxy.conf** :

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

Then I started mitmproxy on machine 2:

```
mitmproxy --rawtcp
```

Then I tried to run an application, but mitmproxy shows a warning when something is trying to connect to a database. An example:

```
Warn: 192.168.56.1:51204: HTTP protocol error in client request: Bad HTTP request line: b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01...
```

What am I doing wrong?